# MySQL Error - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I have a bash script that's supposed to talk to a MySQL database like this:

```
mysql --login-path=local  -e "DROP SCHEMA mydatabase;"
```

When the script tries to connect to MySQL, it gives the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

System info:

- ubuntu server 18.04
- mysql 5.7.28

MySQL Install Info:

Apt installed mysql, ran `mysql_secure_installation`

Set root password:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Created `~/.my.cnf` file:

```
[local]  
user=root  
password=mypassword
```

I'm new to MySQL and imagine the solution is simple, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  How can I make this work without changing the bash script?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work using the config editor.

From terminal:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

Comment: the actual answer is that you missed the --password` argument

Answer (score 0):

mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
It worked for my. I just typed: mysql -u root -p after copying and pasting the above.